# Can I stop a WordPress application from using my Gravatar photo?

Tags: privacy, wordpress, gravatar

I uploaded a photo to Gravatar.

Today, I just registered to post on a site running WordPress. Because personal health is discussed on this site, I used a pseudonym on the site, but much to my dismay, it seems like it's going to automatically display my picture from Gravatar. I looked through all the options in WordPress, and I see that I can change my displayed username, but there is no way to specify my Gravatar.

Is there a way to stop this WordPress site from displaying my photo, short of simply not using that site?

Comment: @pnuts, perhaps that would be a good idea, but it seems awfully odd that there would be a prominent option to change my displayed username, but no option to change my photo displayed (or even any indication that the photo comes from Gravatar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not a Gravatar photo is displayed when you comment on a WordPress-based site depends on HOW exactly you connect to that site.

And you also need to understand that Gravatar.com and WordPress.com are provided by the same company, and usernames are shared across both. Thus, if you connect to the site using your WordPress.com account, then your corresponding Gravatar photo will (or at least can) get shown. In order to rule out this possibility, make sure you are not logged in to WordPress.com or Gravatar.com before (and while) commenting on the site.

Assuming then that you will be identifying yourself to the site only via an email address, make sure to give an address that does not have a corresponding Gravatar.com photo registered.

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent WordPress from using Gravatar, but you can head over to the [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/emails/) site & change which email ID can use which gravatar.